# Is there any internal mapping of an object's hashcode to what we override in our classes

Tags: java

Sets care about uniqueness, so while implementing set in our program we must override the `java.lang.Object` `equals()` and `hashCode()` method, so that we do not end up with duplicates. A reference holds its validity within the context of the single and current instance of the JVM, keeping this in mind I tried to code my program this way. Within `TestSet.main` (lines 4-6). I have tried to put my query in a practical way by using comments in those lines.

```
class TestCase  {
    transient private int x;
    private int y;
    public TestCase(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof TestCase && (((TestCase) o).getXValue() == getYValue()))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return x + y;
    }
    public int getXValue() {
        return x;
    }
    public int getYValue() {
        return y;
    }
}

class TestSet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestCase tc1 = new TestCase(4, 8);
        TestCase tc2 = new TestCase(4, 8);
        Set<TestCase> set = new HashSet<TestCase>();
        set.add(tc1);//succeeds
        set.add(tc2);//succeeds
        System.out.println(set.add(tc2));//fails and gives us false.
        tc2 = new TestCase(4, 8);
        System.out.println(set.add(tc2));//succeeds and gives us true?
        System.out.println(set.size());
        System.out.println(set.contains(tc1));
        System.out.println(set.contains(tc2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `equals()` is wrong, since you're comparing `this.x` to `o.y` (apples to oranges). You need to compare *both* `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your equals method: you are comparing one element's `x` to the other's `y`.  This makes pretty much no sense; you should be comparing both x's and both y's.

You should implement `equals` as

```
return o instanceof TestCase
   && ((TestCase) o).getXValue() == getXValue()
   && ((TestCase) o).getYValue() == getYValue();
```

The reason the second `.add(tc2)` returns `false` is because `HashSet`'s implementation uses a `==` check as an optimization, and that happens to catch that particular case.  That doesn't change the brokenness of your `.equals` method.

Comment: using an appropriate override was not my intention but using legal was, but thank you louis for letting me know the type of implementation HashSet class uses.

Comment: I suggest to add reference check before checking internal data. Something like this return (o == this) || (o instanceof TestCase
   && ((TestCase) o).getXValue() == getXValue()
   && ((TestCase) o).getYValue() == getYValue());

Comment: This always helps to speed up things ;)

Comment: @GevorgHarutyunyan ...why would you say that?  As I already mentioned, `HashSet` does a `==` check for you.  Doing it a second time is pointless; I'd expect that to hurt performance, not help.

Comment: Just in case some other class would not do that.

Comment: @GevorgHarutyunyan, what other class?  99% of the code calling `hashCode` on any given class is going to be `HashSet` and `HashMap`.  You're hurting performance for that 99% case just to improve performance in the 1% case.

Comment: Ok, don't do that. I don't have stats for usage, from my experience it was always good practice. I don't have stats like 99% to prove it however.

Answer (score 0):

The rule that `equals` and `hashCode` must conform to is: if two objects are equal, then their hash codes must be the same.

Note that this does **not** mean the opposite: if two objects have the same hash code, it does not necessarily mean that the objects are equal.

Your code violates this rule, so you get unpredictable results when you put those two objects in a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

First you better fix or remove your equals method completely. Your situation has nothing to do with how hashCode method is working, I will explain how it works below:

```
// Set is looking for tc2 and finds object with same ref, because of previous set.add(tc2);
System.out.println(set.add(tc2));//fails and gives us false.

// You create new object with new reference.
tc2 = new TestCase(4, 8);

// Yes, because you changed tc2 variable and assigned new reference to it.
System.out.println(set.add(tc2));//succeeds and gives us true?
```